# Plotting two large columns

Tags: plotting

I have two large columns of data which both have a dimension of `{2485,1}`. Now I want to plot these two columns versus together. I have tried 
`ListLinePlot[{col1, col2}]` but it doesn't give the correct plot. I think that it draws both columns versus ordered numbers (1,2,3,...). However, I need a plot which its x-axis be `col1` and its y-axis be `col2`. How can I obtain such a plot?

Comment: No, it returns just an empty plot!

Comment: It doesn't work!

Comment: @Wisdom what is the error message? ListLinePlot[Transpose[{col1, col2}]] should work.

Comment: @PicaudVincent  It doesn't return any error but an empty graph (namely just two axes). Is it possible my large data cause such a situation?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Thanks a lot

Comment: What do you mean by "namely they aren't lists"? What does `Dimensions[col1]` return?

Comment: @Roman both of them return `{2485,1}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ListLinePlot[Transpose[Flatten /@ {col1, col2}]]
```

The problem is that your `col1` and `col2` aren't lists, as you say, but rather they are $2485\times1$ matrices.

Comment: Thanks, it workes, however, this command gives me a plot which has not the appropriate x-axis. Namely the correct x-axis starts by 613 and ends up by 0.000001 for example. this is while the obtained plot has an x-axis which starts at 0 and ends by 2.5! what is the problem?

Comment: Have you tried `PlotRange->All`?

Comment: Ohhh my god! it worked finally! Thanks a lot, dear Roman. I didn't know it is necessary to write the range because I thought that Mathematica includes all of my data. Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome. Don't hesitate to up-vote and to accept the answer.

Comment: another question: how can I tell Mathematica to compress some rigions of x-axis and expand some other regions? In fact, I want to enhance the resolution of my graph because the variations of my data are not the same on all x-axis

Comment: You'd have to ask more specifically. Please open a separate question for this.